Problems with Lucene syntax in search text
I'm trying to do some vector search using Azure AI Search. I have an index with 30 features and I want to search using Lucene syntax in search text but I do not understand well its functioning.
In particular, I have some problem when I am trying to do a request in Python using the SearchClient:
filters = "Thickness ge 6"

text = "Color:WHITE"

results = search_client.search(
  query_type="full",
  search_text=text,
  vector_queries=vector_query,
  filter=filters,
  select=retrievable_field_names, # all the fields
  top=15
)

In particular, I expect to obtain higher scores with elements which have "WHITE" as part of the value of the feature "Color" (in fact, I'm not using Color in filters because sometimes the value of Color includes other elements other than "WHITE").
Anyway, I obtain higher scores in elements with both Color value including WHITE and that have also other features including WHITE (i.e., if another feature, i.e. Collections, include WHITE as substring, it will receive an higher score). This is a behavior I would like to avoid.
What should I do in this case?

Try boosting that feature. check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#bkmk_termboost
